# How to implement controllers for extension backend part in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I need to implement a custom action for saving the data of extension admin pages.

Comment: What exactly do you want to archive? What did you try so far? Please give some more information and code snippets. And please read the guide on how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: @PeterKraume I have created a simple extension based on [link]https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation-Examples/store_inventory, I need to extend the save functionality such that on saving a product a notification mail should send.
How can I implement this?

I heard about hooks but I am not clear?

Answer (score 0):

I would storage the mailing logic in an external utility and then instance it in the controller.
For example in EmailUtility you have a method called sendMail($emailAddress) and then you create an instance of this Utility in the controller and after saving the data in the repository you send the email with $emailUtility->sendEmail($emailAddress).

For the email you can use the Email API (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html)